# How to check whether the sum of any two integers in an array exists as an item in the array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm

I'm writing a function that returns true if the sum of any two integers in an array exists as an item in the array. For example:

```
[3, 4, 8, 11]
//returns true because 8 + 3 = 11 

[2, 4, 7, 12]
//returns false
```

So far, I've got this:

```
const checkArray = (arr) => {
  arr.sort((a, b) => a - b);
  let lhs = 0;
  let rhs = array.length - 1;

  while (lhs < rhs) {
    const sum = arr[lhs] + arr[rhs];

    if (arr.includes(sum)) {
      return true;
    } else if (arr[lhs] < sum) {
      lhs++;
    } else {
      rhs--;
    }
  }
  return true;
}
```

Been at it for a while, can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Have you tried debugging for a small failing example yet? What where your findings?

Comment: `return false;` should be the default

Comment: It should be `arr.length -1` instead of `array.length - 1`.

Comment: I don't understand the idea behind the algorithm, and as is, it doesn't work. Can you elaborate?

Comment: After a bit of research, your code looks like a stripped/broken version of the stereotypical [quadratic 3SUM implementation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3SUM#Quadratic_algorithm). I am not sure anymore, whether this is actually your code, or some arbitrarily broken version of linked code, without any explanation about the source, or idea behind the edits (which don't work). You also seem to have gone dead since posting this.

Answer (score 0):

I try to do without sort:

```
const checkArray = (arr) => {
  if (arr.length < 2) return false;
  let lhs = 0;
  while (lhs < arr.length - 2) {
    let rhs = lhs + 1;
    while (rhs <= arr.length - 1) {
      if (arr.includes(arr[lhs] + arr[rhs])) {
        return true;
      }
      rhs += 1;
    }
    lhs += 1;
  }
  return false;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [Array.prototype.some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) with [Array.prototype.find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

```
const checkArray = (array) => {
    //Wll only return true if the inner array.some returns true
    return array.some((num, index) => {
        return array.some((innernum, innerIndex) => {
            //Will return true if current number is === to any two numbers
            return innerIndex !== index && !!array.find(item => item === (innernum + num))
        })
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could take a nested approach where a value and a sum is take for generating a mssing value.

```js
function check(array) {
    const
        need = {};

    for (let i = 0; i < array.length - 1; i++) {
        if (need[array[i]]) return true;
        for (let j = array.length - 1; j > i + 1; j--) {
            need[array[j] - array[i]] = true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

console.log(check([1, 2, 3]));     //  true
console.log(check([3, 4, 8, 11])); //  true
console.log(check([2, 4, 7, 12])); // false
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code...

```
//const arr = [3,4,8,11];
//const arr = [2, 4, 7, 12];

const checkArray = (arr) => {
   var a = [];
   for(var i=0; i<arr.length-1; i++){
      for(var j=i+1; j<arr.length; j++){
          a.push(arr[i]+arr[j]);
       }
    }
    for(var x of arr){
       if(a.indexOf(x) != -1){
           return true;
        }
     }
  return false;
}

console.log(checkArray(arr));
```

If this code helps please let me know...!